# Crystal Reports Formula: Help forming IIF Statement

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working with Crystal Reports 11.5.10.1263 [CR Developer Type: Full].

I am familiar with Programming and SQL syntax in general and have worked with expressions in SSRS & MS Access but never in Crystal Reports.

Problem:

I modified the SQL in the Crystal report and it has had the desired effect - except in the last part of the report output - where the changes I made to the SQL do not have the desired effect.

The 'desired effect' is that when a field named 'FundNumber' has the values '2595', '2597' Then the field named 'Organization' should be assigned the value '41600'.

The Detail Record in the Report has the following three rows as part of its 'Formula':

```
+ IIf({Data.Payments} > 0, "+01W      ", "-01W      ")  
+ Left({Data.FundNumber}+ SPACE(6),6)
+ Left({Data.Organization}+ SPACE(6),6)
```

I want to change the Data.Organization row to an IIF Statement that says [pseucode]:

```
IIf Data.FundNumber IN ["2595", "2597"] Then "41600" Else Data.Organization
```

I believe the Left() function is saying 'return the left 6 characters of [Data.Organization + 6 Spaces] ?? and that it has to do with the way the data is presented in the output.

I would appreciate help with creating the IIF statement for this.
I included the 'IIf({Data.Payments} ...' row in case that helps - as my google searches have turned up examples that use IF instead of IIF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax most of the time is the same as VB. Try

```
IIF({Data.FundNumber} = "2595" or {Data.FundNumber} = "2597", "41600", {Data.Organization})
```